# How to add GDAL Programs folder to ~/.bash_profile

Tags: python, gdal, mac

I have recently installed on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4 the GDAL Framework 1.9 with Python bindings from [http://www.kyngchaos.com/software:frameworks][1].

I need to add the following Programs folder to my ~/.bash_profile as described in the ReadMe file:

`export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH`

This is what's currently on my ~/.bash_profile:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

What is the right syntax for adding the new path?

I am new with everything (Mac, Python and GDAL) so please excuse me if I wasn't clear.

Many Thanks

Andrea

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit off-topic, but it's an easy fix. In the BASH shell, the colon character is used to separate paths in a list, and the `${PATH}` evaluates to whatever the `PATH` environment variable was. So you can either add the GDAL path as a separate line:

```
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:${PATH}
export PATH
```

or put it all on one line:

```
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:${PATH}
export PATH
```

It's entirely up to you: either way, you'll end up with the same path list.

Comment: Or really put it all on one line: export PATH=...

Comment: And don't forget to quote the whole thing, since there's a slight chance the existing path may contain whitespace.